# 'Probability method' - to what extent is it an actual proof?

Tags: probability

Consider this:

> $\frac { C^{2n}_n } {2^{2n}} = \mathbb P (A) $   where A= { equal number of heads and tails in $2n$ throws of a fair coin }
>
> therefore the following assertion is true:
>
>  $\forall n \ge 0 : \ \  0 \le \frac { C^{2n}_n } {2^{2n}} \le 1$

my question is: To what extent is this a bona-fide 'proof' of the assertion, if at all?

Comment: Did you mean to have $2^{2n}$ in the denominator?

Comment: now fixed, very sorry

Comment: On the one hand, it's not a proof.  On the other hand, any experienced mathematician will immediately see that this argument can easily be *turned into* a proof, and will therefore consider it a good as a proof (and will probably use language loosely enough to just go ahead and call it a proof).

Comment: I see the edit.  sure, your argument is a proof...you show that your number equals a number which is manifestly $≤1$.  Of course, you can avoid reference to $A$ altogether...your number is the portion of subsets of {$1,...,2n$} which have exactly $n$ elements.  Clearly that portion is $≤1$.

Comment: Note:  I agree entirely with the comment of @WillO ...and, as predicted there, I am just using language loosely and I'm going to go ahead and call the argument a proof. I think we'd both agree that the reference to probability (the heart, I think, of your question) in no way makes the argument less rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a perfectly valid argument.  If you know that the formula corresponds to a probability, the value must be between $0$ and $1$, because all probabilities are.  However, as a "proof" it lacks bona-fides in the sense that a proof proceeds from commonly-accepted premises (axioms) to less-obvious conclusions (theorems), and here you are working essentially the opposite way, since the validity of the formula is much less obvious (to most people) than the fact that a probability must be between $0$ and $1$ (which is in fact one of the [probability axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbabilityAxioms.html)).  That said, there is nothing wrong with reasoning this way.  In the right context it could be really slick.  One thing to watch out for is cases when the formula isn't valid as a probability, for example negative values of $n$.

You may be interested in Erdos' [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) which is basically a way of showing something exists because its probability is non-zero.

Comment: I was worried that 'complicated expression X = P(some event) in some probability space'  merely indicated the plausibility of '0 <= X <=1 ' , rather than provided an actual proof.

Comment: It might only indicate that, for example you might have some formula that takes on lots of different values but it is only valid as a probability formula when its value is between $0$ and $1$.  Consider "the probability that person uses email is equal to 100% minus their age"...  it doesn't mean that probability can be negative just because some people live over a century.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a subsets of events in an event space, you don't even need to use the "axiom" that a probability is between 0 and 1. Simply consider the set of all possible outcomes when you flip $2n$ independent coins. This is an event space with $2^{2n}$ events, as you noted, and also which is very easy to show. The subset of cases when you get $n$ heads and $n$ tails is obviously strictly smaller. The harder part is proving that any actual formula you get for counting this subset of events is correct.